# AWS ElasticBeanstalk multicontainer - docker run "--pid=host" option

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was trying to deploy "https://github.com/nicolargo/glances", but was unable to find runtime parameter "--pid=host" in beanstalk JSON definition.

Docker run ref -
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#pid-settings---pid

ECS Task definition parameters -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#standard_container_definition_params

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing of host's PID with the container is not [supported by ECS at the moment](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/473)

Comment: `networkMode = "host"` seems to be supported by ECS but not by Beanstalk, right?

Comment: that is correct, beanstalk doesn't support it yet (last I checked)